# extra space between search bar and searchResultsController

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

[image]

```
    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: ResultsController())
        searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.Custom.theme
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    }
```

I want to know how to make searchResultsController stick below searchBar ... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
In parent controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

    // Your code
}
```

Comment: That extends under the bottom bar as well.